# Having an 'or' in match arm's on Rust

Tags: rust, match

So I have the next code on Rust:

```rust
match val.cmp(&n) {
    Ordering::Less => {
        foo();
    }
    Ordering::Equal => {
        bar();
    }
    Ordering::Greater => {
        bar();
    }
};
```

As you can see the content for the `Ordering::Equal` and `Ordering::Greater` are the same. Is there a way to call `bar()` just once in a some sort of pattern for the arm case?

I've tried with an "or" (`||`) :

```rust
match val.cmp(&n) {
    Ordering::Less => {
        foo();
    }
    Ordering::Greater || Ordering::Equal => {
        bar();
    }
};
```

And with a tuple:

```rust
match val.cmp(&n) {
    Ordering::Less => {
        foo();
    }
    (Ordering::Greater, Ordering::Equal) => {
        bar();
    }
};
```

Is it possible?

Comment: yes, use `|` ...

Comment: Read the error message: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7e38ba335dba8d3b81c67147a6409557